# Shall we introduce deletion_protection attribute to "important" Terraform resources to protect against deletion on top of the prevent_destroy?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Context: I'm developing a TF Provider using Terraform SDKv2.

I've noticed there's `prevent_destroy` [attribute](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#prevent_destroy) that should protect against accidental deletions of important resources (that should only be deleted in exceptional cases).

However it looks like it won't prevent from issues where the resource is accidentally removed from the TF configuration or some other silly developer error, since the `prevent_destroy` attribute will be lost as well and not applied.

And then we noticed there's `deletion_protection` attribute for `aws_rds_cluster` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster) of AWS TF Provider. Is it a thing or there're any other built in mechanism to address it?

For example, GCP's [Best practices for using Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/best-practices-for-terraform) mentions:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "main" {
  name = "primary-instance"
  settings {
    tier = "D0"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

so it sounds like `prevent_destroy` might be good enough. That said, there's `deletion_protection` attribute for `sql_database_instance` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance) too. What's even more interesting, for `google_bigquery_table` `deletion_protection` attribute [defaults](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/google/resource_bigquery_table.go#L931) to `true` and there's a [note](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table):

> : On newer versions of the provider, you must explicitly set deletion_protection=false (and run terraform apply to write the field to state) in order to destroy an instance. It is recommended to not set this field (or set it to true) until you're ready to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

There are two flags in terraform for `google_sql_database_instance`.

#### deletion_protection (mentioned in your question)

> - (Optional) Whether or not to allow Terraform to destroy the instance. Unless this field is set to false in Terraform state, a
>   terraform destroy or terraform apply command that deletes the instance
>   will fail. Defaults to true.

This updates the terraform metadata and will not allow you to delete the resource via terraform if enabled.

Docs : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#deletion_protection

#### settings.deletion_protection_enabled

It is for setting deletion protection on cloudsql instance itself.

> deletion_protection_enabled - (Optional) Enables deletion protection
> of an instance at the GCP level. Enabling this protection will guard
> against accidental deletion across all surfaces (API, gcloud, Cloud
> Console and Terraform) by enabling the GCP Cloud SQL instance deletion
> protection. Terraform provider support was introduced in version
> 4.48.0. Defaults to false.

Docs : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#deletion_protection_enabled